# Working Soap client example

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm trying to find a simple (ha) SOAP example in JAVA with a working service, any I seem to be finding are not working.

I have tried this [one](http://www.elharo.com/fibonacci/SOAP) from this [example](http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch03s05.html) but it's just not working, it's asking me to put a forward slash in but it's in there and nothing happening.

So does anyone know any SOAP example links, I can download/request and mess with?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looking for documentation about this on 2019 is even harder...

Answer (score 232, accepted):

To implement simple SOAP clients in Java, you can use the SAAJ framework (it is shipped with JSE 1.6 and above, but removed again in Java 11):

> **SOAP with Attachments API for Java (SAAJ)** is mainly used for dealing directly with SOAP Request/Response messages which happens behind the scenes in any Web Service API. It allows the developers to directly send and receive soap messages instead of using JAX-WS.

See below a working example (run it!) of a SOAP web service call using SAAJ. It calls [this web service](http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?op=GetInfoByCity).

```
import javax.xml.soap.*;

public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

    // SAAJ - SOAP Client Testing
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
            The example below requests from the Web Service at:
             http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?op=GetInfoByCity


            To call other WS, change the parameters below, which are:
             - the SOAP Endpoint URL (that is, where the service is responding from)
             - the SOAP Action

            Also change the contents of the method createSoapEnvelope() in this class. It constructs
             the inner part of the SOAP envelope that is actually sent.
         */
        String soapEndpointUrl = "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx";
        String soapAction = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetInfoByCity";

        callSoapWebService(soapEndpointUrl, soapAction);
    }

    private static void createSoapEnvelope(SOAPMessage soapMessage) throws SOAPException {
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String myNamespace = "myNamespace";
        String myNamespaceURI = "http://www.webserviceX.NET";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(myNamespace, myNamespaceURI);

            /*
            Constructed SOAP Request Message:
            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:myNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
                <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
                <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                    <myNamespace:GetInfoByCity>
                        <myNamespace:USCity>New York</myNamespace:USCity>
                    </myNamespace:GetInfoByCity>
                </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
            */

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("GetInfoByCity", myNamespace);
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("USCity", myNamespace);
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("New York");
    }

    private static void callSoapWebService(String soapEndpointUrl, String soapAction) {
        try {
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(soapAction), soapEndpointUrl);

            // Print the SOAP Response
            System.out.println("Response SOAP Message:");
            soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println();

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("\nError occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server!\nMake sure you have the correct endpoint URL and SOAPAction!\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String soapAction) throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

        createSoapEnvelope(soapMessage);

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message, just for debugging purposes */
        System.out.println("Request SOAP Message:");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println("\n");

        return soapMessage;
    }

}
```

Comment: Got this error `<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: .</faultstring>`

Comment: The SOAPAction HTTP header was missing. Corrected it by adding the lines `MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders(); headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://ws.cdyne.com/VerifyEmail");`. I now think it's strange it worked before without it. :)

Comment: Do you know a good way of parsing the elements of the result?

Comment: Parsing them into an object or just making it, for instance, a `Map` of `String`s for easier accessing?

Comment: @acdcjunior In this example, if I remove the line - soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);, the request gives an error response. Weird, but its happening. Any idea about why that would happen?

Comment: @A.J Do you have more specifics? Does the javar error code fails, or the message goes to the webservice but the webservice responds with a fault, or something else}?

Comment: @acdcjunior the message goes to the service and returns something like - SOAPAction not defined. From the javadoc, I noticed that SOAPMessage.writeTo() internally calls SOAPMessage.saveChanges(). Calling the SOAPMessage.saveChanges() directly w/o using writeTo doesnt seem to work

Comment: Best example on the internet.  The serialization technique never works correctly in the real world where people can do all sorts of weird things in the definition files.

Comment: I have tried you example, but I get this error `Failed to determine BusFactory implementation class name.: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory`. Any clues?

Comment: is there a way to strip SOAP-ENV: off of the request?

Comment: @Jeef Take a look at this one, maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577207/use-default-namespace-in-valid-soap-saaj-envelope/

Comment: @Jeef you can try `envelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration("SOAP-ENV");`

Comment: What do you put for "example" in ``envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);``. Would that be something like ``urn``?

Comment: @santafebound `"example"` will become the namespace prefix for that URI. In the example, its effects are seen in `<example:VerifyEmail>`. In other words, if you used `envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("argh", serverURI);`, that element would be  `<argh:VerifyEmail>`.

Comment: @acdcjunior My URL has a Message saying "Your connection is not secure" How can I bypass it in eclipse? So that, my soapConnection.call(createSOAPReqeuest(),url); would work?

Comment: I  need to pass credntails with this call , Can u please help me out to call with credentals

Comment: If you need to use SOAP 1.2 , you just need to change `MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();` to `MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);` - I have spent a lot of time trying to change default namespace from `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` to `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope` , but this is the only thing that really helped

Comment: i cant understand "createSoapEnvelope(soapMessage);"" in "createSOAPRequest(String soapAction)" method. why changes "soapMessage"  by calling static method? java is pass-by-value ... :\

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you can acquire any WSDL file, then you can use SoapUI to create mock service of that service complete with unit test requests.  I [created an example of this (using Maven) that you can try out](https://github.com/djangofan/soapui-maven-template).

Comment: Link to your example returns 404. Could you possibly get it back?

Answer (score 3):

> Calculator SOAP service test from [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/), [Online SoapClient Calculator](http://www.soapclient.com/soapclient?template=%2Fclientform.html&fn=soapform&SoapTemplate=%2FSoapResult.html&SoapWSDL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dneonline.com%2Fcalculator.asmx%3Fwsdl&_ArraySize=2)

[image]

Generate the `SoapMessage` object form the input `SoapEnvelopeXML` and `SoapDataXml`.

> SoapEnvelopeXML

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Add xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
         <tem:intA>3</tem:intA>
         <tem:intB>4</tem:intB>
      </tem:Add>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

use the following code to get SoapMessage Object.

```java
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    MimeHeaders headers = new MimeHeaders();
    ByteArrayInputStream xmlByteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(SoapEnvelopeXML.getBytes());
SOAPMessage soapMsg = messageFactory.createMessage(headers, xmlByteStream);
```

> SoapDataXml

```xml
<tem:Add xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <tem:intA>3</tem:intA>
    <tem:intB>4</tem:intB>
</tem:Add>
```

use below code to get SoapMessage Object.

```java
public static SOAPMessage getSOAPMessagefromDataXML(String saopBodyXML) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource ips = new org.xml.sax.InputSource(new StringReader(saopBodyXML));
    Document docBody = dBuilder.parse(ips);
    System.out.println("Data Document: "+docBody.getDocumentElement());
    
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
    SOAPMessage soapMsg = messageFactory.createMessage();
    
    SOAPBody soapBody = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();
    soapBody.addDocument(docBody);
    
    return soapMsg;
}
```

---

By getting the SoapMessage Object. It is clear that the Soap XML is valid. Then prepare to hit the service to get response. It can be done in many ways.

1. Using Client Code Generated form WSDL.

```java
java.net.URL endpointURL = new java.net.URL(endPointUrl);
javax.xml.rpc.Service service = new org.apache.axis.client.Service();
((org.apache.axis.client.Service) service).setTypeMappingVersion("1.2");
CalculatorSoap12Stub obj_axis = new CalculatorSoap12Stub(endpointURL, service);
int add = obj_axis.add(10, 20);
System.out.println("Response: "+ add);
```

2. Using `javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection`.

```java
public static void getSOAPConnection(SOAPMessage soapMsg) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("===== SOAPConnection =====");
    MimeHeaders headers = soapMsg.getMimeHeaders(); // new MimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SoapBinding",   serverDetails.get("SoapBinding") );
    headers.addHeader("MethodName",    serverDetails.get("MethodName") );
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction",    serverDetails.get("SOAPAction") );
    headers.addHeader("Content-Type",  serverDetails.get("Content-Type"));
    headers.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", serverDetails.get("Accept-Encoding"));
    if (soapMsg.saveRequired()) {
        soapMsg.saveChanges();
    }
    
    SOAPConnectionFactory newInstance = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection connection = newInstance.createConnection();
    SOAPMessage soapMsgResponse = connection.call(soapMsg, getURL( serverDetails.get("SoapServerURI"), 5*1000 ));
    
    getSOAPXMLasString(soapMsgResponse);
}
```

3. Form HTTP Connection Classes `org.apache.commons.httpclient`.

```java
public static void getHttpConnection(SOAPMessage soapMsg) throws SOAPException, IOException {
    System.out.println("===== HttpClient =====");
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpConnectionManagerParams params = httpClient.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams();
    params.setConnectionTimeout(3 * 1000); // Connection timed out
    params.setSoTimeout(3 * 1000);         // Request timed out
    params.setParameter("http.useragent", "Web Service Test Client");

    PostMethod methodPost = new PostMethod( serverDetails.get("SoapServerURI") );
    methodPost.setRequestBody( getSOAPXMLasString(soapMsg) );
    methodPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", serverDetails.get("Content-Type") );
    methodPost.setRequestHeader("SoapBinding",  serverDetails.get("SoapBinding") );
    methodPost.setRequestHeader("MethodName",   serverDetails.get("MethodName") );
    methodPost.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",   serverDetails.get("SOAPAction") );

    methodPost.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", serverDetails.get("Accept-Encoding"));

    try {
        int returnCode = httpClient.executeMethod(methodPost);
        if (returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
            System.out.println("The Post method is not implemented by this URI");
            methodPost.getResponseBodyAsString();
        } else {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(methodPost.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
            String readLine;
            while (((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                System.out.println(readLine);
            }
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        methodPost.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

```java
public static void accessResource_AppachePOST(SOAPMessage soapMsg) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("===== HttpClientBuilder =====");
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder( serverDetails.get("SoapServerURI") );
    HttpPost methodPost = new HttpPost(builder.build());
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5 * 1000)
            .setSocketTimeout(5 * 1000)
            .build();
    methodPost.setConfig(config);
        HttpEntity xmlEntity = new StringEntity(getSOAPXMLasString(soapMsg), "utf-8");
    methodPost.setEntity(xmlEntity);
        
    methodPost.setHeader("Content-Type", serverDetails.get("Content-Type"));
    methodPost.setHeader("SoapBinding", serverDetails.get("SoapBinding") );
    methodPost.setHeader("MethodName", serverDetails.get("MethodName") );
    methodPost.setHeader("SOAPAction", serverDetails.get("SOAPAction") );
    methodPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", serverDetails.get("Accept-Encoding"));
    
    // Create a custom response handler
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
        @Override
        public String handleResponse( final HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status >= 200 && status <= 500) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
            }
            return "";
        }
    };
    String execute = httpClient.execute( methodPost, responseHandler );
    System.out.println("AppachePOST : "+execute);
}
```

Full Example:

```java
public class SOAP_Calculator {
    static HashMap<String, String> serverDetails = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        // Calculator
        serverDetails.put("SoapServerURI", "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx");
        serverDetails.put("SoapWSDL", "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl");
        serverDetails.put("SoapBinding", "CalculatorSoap");        // <wsdl:binding name="CalculatorSoap12" type="tns:CalculatorSoap">
        serverDetails.put("MethodName", "Add");                    // <wsdl:operation name="Add">
        serverDetails.put("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/Add"); // <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Add" style="document"/>
        serverDetails.put("SoapXML", "<tem:Add xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><tem:intA>2</tem:intA><tem:intB>4</tem:intB></tem:Add>");
        
        serverDetails.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        serverDetails.put("Content-Type", "");
    }
    public static void callSoapService( ) throws Exception {
        String xmlData = serverDetails.get("SoapXML");
        
        SOAPMessage soapMsg = getSOAPMessagefromDataXML(xmlData);
        System.out.println("Requesting SOAP Message:\n"+ getSOAPXMLasString(soapMsg) +"\n");
        
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        if (envelope.getElementQName().getNamespaceURI().equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")) {
            System.out.println("SOAP 1.1 NamespaceURI: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            serverDetails.put("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        } else {
            System.out.println("SOAP 1.2 NamespaceURI: http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
            serverDetails.put("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
        }
        
        getHttpConnection(soapMsg);
        getSOAPConnection(soapMsg);
        accessResource_AppachePOST(soapMsg);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        callSoapService();
    }

    private static URL getURL(String endPointUrl, final int timeOutinSeconds) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL endpoint = new URL(null, endPointUrl, new URLStreamHandler() {
            protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
                URL clone = new URL(url.toString());
                URLConnection connection = clone.openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(timeOutinSeconds);
                connection.setReadTimeout(timeOutinSeconds);
                //connection.addRequestProperty("Developer-Mood", "Happy"); // Custom header
                return connection;
            }
        });
        return endpoint;
    }
    public static String getSOAPXMLasString(SOAPMessage soapMsg) throws SOAPException, IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        soapMsg.writeTo(out);
        // soapMsg.writeTo(System.out);
        String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
        System.out.println("Soap XML: "+ strMsg);
        return strMsg;
    }
}
```

@See list of some WebServices at http://sofa.uqam.ca/soda/webservices.php

Answer (score 1):

The response of acdcjunior it was awesome, I just expand his explanation with the next code, where you can see how iterate over the XML elements.

```
public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // Create SOAP Connection
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
    String url = "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);



    SOAPPart soapPart=soapResponse.getSOAPPart();
    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope=soapPart.getEnvelope();
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Iterator<Node> itr=soapBody.getChildElements();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {

        Node node=(Node)itr.next();
        if (node.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            System.out.println("reading Node.ELEMENT_NODE");
            Element ele=(Element)node;
            System.out.println("Body childs : "+ele.getLocalName());

            switch (ele.getNodeName()) {

          case "VerifyEmailResponse":
             NodeList statusNodeList = ele.getChildNodes();

             for(int i=0;i<statusNodeList.getLength();i++){
               Element emailResult = (Element) statusNodeList.item(i);
               System.out.println("VerifyEmailResponse childs : "+emailResult.getLocalName());
                switch (emailResult.getNodeName()) {

                case "VerifyEmailResult":
                    NodeList emailResultList = emailResult.getChildNodes();

                    for(int j=0;j<emailResultList.getLength();j++){
                      Element emailResponse = (Element) emailResultList.item(j);
                      System.out.println("VerifyEmailResult childs : "+emailResponse.getLocalName());
                       switch (emailResponse.getNodeName()) {
                       case "ResponseText":
                           System.out.println(emailResponse.getTextContent());
                           break;
                        case "ResponseCode":
                          System.out.println(emailResponse.getTextContent());
                           break;
                        case "LastMailServer":
                          System.out.println(emailResponse.getTextContent());
                          break;
                        case "GoodEmail":
                          System.out.println(emailResponse.getTextContent());
                       default:
                          break;
                       }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                   break;
                }
             }


             break;


          default:
             break;
          }

        } else if (node.getNodeType()==Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            System.out.println("reading Node.TEXT_NODE");
            //do nothing here most likely, as the response nearly never has mixed content type
            //this is just for your reference
        }
    }
    // print SOAP Response
    System.out.println("Response SOAP Message:");
    soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

    soapConnection.close();
}

private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);

    /*
    Constructed SOAP Request Message:
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:example="http://ws.cdyne.com/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <example:VerifyEmail>
                <example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email>
                <example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey>
            </example:VerifyEmail>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
     */

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("VerifyEmail", "example");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("email", "example");
    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("mutantninja@gmail.com");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("LicenseKey", "example");
    soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("123");

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "VerifyEmail");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    /* Print the request message */
    System.out.println("Request SOAP Message:");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("------");

    return soapMessage;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone who have xml request as string and want to hit soap request from Java like me.
if you have WSDL, You can create a new soap request in SoapUI with that WSDL file.
It would automatically generate the Structure/XML for input request.

Here is some simple version of Java code you can use to call Soap service if you have the input request xml from SoapUI:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class SimpleSoapClient {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        
    String address="Hyderabad";

    /* place your xml request from soap ui below with necessary changes in parameters*/
    
    String xml="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ws=\"http://www.YourUrlAsPerWsdl.com/\">\r\n" + 
                 "   <soapenv:Header/>\r\n" + 
                 "   <soapenv:Body>\r\n" + 
                 "      <ws:callRest>\r\n" + 
                 "         <name>"+"Hello"+"</name>\r\n" + 
                 "         <address>"+address+"</address>\r\n" + 
                 "      </ws:callRest>\r\n" + 
                 "   </soapenv:Body>\r\n" + 
                 "</soapenv:Envelope>";
            String responseF=callSoapService(xml);
            System.out.println(responseF);
    }
    

}

static String callSoapService(String soapRequest) {
    try {
     String url = "https://gogle.com/service/hello"; // replace your URL here
     URL obj = new URL(url);
     HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
     
     // change these values as per soapui request on top left of request, click on RAW, you will find all the headers
     con.setRequestMethod("POST");
     con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8"); 
     con.setDoOutput(true);
     DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
     wr.writeBytes(soapRequest);
     wr.flush();
     wr.close();
     String responseStatus = con.getResponseMessage();
     System.out.println(responseStatus);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     con.getInputStream()));
     String inputLine;
     StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
         response.append(inputLine);
     }
     in.close();
     
     // You can play with response which is available as string now:
     String finalvalue= response.toString();
     
     // or you can parse/substring the required tag from response as below based your response code
     finalvalue= finalvalue.substring(finalvalue.indexOf("<response>")+10,finalvalue.indexOf("</response>")); */
     
     return finalvalue;
     } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }   
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

For Basic Authentication of WSDL the accepted answers code raises an error. Try the following instead

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password".toCharArray());
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be "password".toBase64()" or something like that?  This is the same code block you would use for javax.email .

Answer (score -5):

```
String send = 
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\n" +
    "        <soap:Body>\n" +
    "        </soap:Body>\n" +
    "</soap:Envelope>";

private static String getResponse(String send) throws Exception {
    String url = "https://api.comscore.com/KeyMeasures.asmx"; //endpoint
    String result = "";
    String username="user_name";
    String password="pass_word";
    String[] command = {"curl", "-u", username+":"+password ,"-X", "POST", "-H", "Content-Type: text/xml", "-d", send, url};
    ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command); 
    Process p;
    try {
        p = process.start();
        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        result = builder.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {   System.out.print("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```