# Use default namespace in valid SOAP SAAJ envelope

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, saaj

Are these two soap messages valid ? The different part is the namespace attribute xmlns="http://www.sigvalue.com/acc". The first soap is a sample, the second one generated by java code to make the same soap message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <GetNGPList xmlns="http://www.sigvalue.com/acc">
  <UserData>
    <senderId>string</senderId>
    <channelId>string</channelId>
    <timeStamp>dateTime</timeStamp>
  </UserData>
  <zipCode>string</zipCode>
</GetNGPList>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetNGPList>
  <UserData xmlns="http://www.sigvalue.com/acc">
    <senderId>string</senderId>
    <channelId>string</channelId>
    <timeStamp>dateTime</timeStamp>
  </UserData xmlns="http://www.sigvalue.com/acc">
  <zipCode>string</zipCode>
</GetNGPList>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**If the second soap is invalid, how could I make it the same as the first one? GetNGPList.addNamespaceDeclaration("xmlns","http://www.sigvalue.com/acc"); this line doesn't work as expected. Here is the  JAVA code :**

```
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();


    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", gXSIServerURI);
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", gXSDServerURI);

        // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement GetNGPList =  soapBody.addChildElement("GetNGPList");
    GetNGPList.addNamespaceDeclaration("xmlns","http://www.sigvalue.com/acc");

    SOAPElement UserData = GetNGPList.addChildElement("UserData");
    SOAPElement senderId = UserData.addChildElement("senderId");
    SOAPElement channelId = UserData.addChildElement("channelId");
    SOAPElement timeStamp = UserData.addChildElement("timeStamp");
    senderId.addTextNode("string");
    channelId.addTextNode("string");
    timeStamp.addTextNode("dateTime");

    SOAPElement zipCode = GetNGPList.addChildElement("zipCode");
    zipCode.addTextNode("string"); 


    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction",  "sample");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    /* Print the request message */
    //System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To set a namespace as the **default namespace**, simply use the **empty string (`""`) as prefix name**:

```
SOAPElement GetNGPList =
       soapBody.addChildElement("GetNGPList", "", "http://www.sigvalue.com/acc");
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The code above will apply `xmlns="http://www.sigvalue.com/acc"` to `GetNGPList`.

Your code, adapted:

```
// SOAP Body
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
SOAPElement GetNGPList =
       soapBody.addChildElement("GetNGPList", "", "http://www.sigvalue.com/acc");

SOAPElement UserData = GetNGPList.addChildElement("UserData");
...
```

As usual, when you omit the namespace prefix declaration in `addChildElement()`, the child inherits its namespace from its parent.

The code above will generate what you needed:

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header />
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <GetNGPList xmlns="http://www.sigvalue.com/acc">
            <UserData>
                <senderId>string</senderId>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this line:

```
GetNGPList.addNamespaceDeclaration("xmlns","http://www.sigvalue.com/acc");
```

and add this line

```
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("","http://www.sigvalue.com/acc");
```

a few notes:

- I suggest using frameworks for working with web services, Apache CXF can do a lot of the tricky work for you: http://cxf.apache.org/
- make sure to follow normal naming standards, it makes in easier to read the code. The variable `GetNGPList` should be `getNGPList`