# Based on WSDL, how can I generate SOAP request on the fly during runtime?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I know there are some tools can help me generate the Web Services client. But, this approach does not work for me, since WSDL is dynamic in my case. So, based on WSDL, is there a Java library can help me generate SOAP request on the fly during runtime?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948927/working-soap-client-example

Answer (score 0):

spring ws with the xsd you can create on fly wsdl.
The trikky part is the configuration of the soapwebservice but here you can find the 80% of the cases.

Regards