# How to add child node for SOAPBody?

Tags: java, soap

I saw [Working Soap client example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948927/working-soap-client-example/15949858#15949858) . But when i add child node for soapbody it throw an exception.

Here is error:

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to locate namespace for prefix ns3

Here is code for SOAPrequest:

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
SOAPElement node1 = soapBody.addChildElement("lookupEligibility","ns3");
```

How to solve it. Thanks!!!!

Comment: soapBody.addChildElement("lookupEligibility","ns3","http://ns3_namespace"); or define ns3 above in your code.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a namespace declaration:

```
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ns3", "your-namespace");
```