# Cleaning up a soap request using SOAPConnectionFactory

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm very new to soap and i found an example of how to do a request here:  [Working Soap client example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948927/working-soap-client-example)

Using a chrome plugin i've managed to find a soap query string that works which is:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <GetMyProjectCharges xmlns="http://company.IWWeb.Data.Service.ProjectCharges">
        <Employee>26270</Employee>
        <FiscalYear>2015</FiscalYear>
        <ApiKey>APIKEY</ApiKey>
        <AppName>APPNAME</AppName>
        </GetMyProjectCharges>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

So trying the code posted from the stack post I wrote:

```
 private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

    // SOAP Envelope

    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

    /*
    Constructed SOAP Request Message:
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:example="http://ws.cdyne.com/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <example:VerifyEmail>
                <example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email>
                <example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey>
            </example:VerifyEmail>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
     */

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();

    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = //soapBody.addChildElement("GetMyProjectCharges");

    soapBody.addChildElement("GetMyProjectCharges", "", "http://company.IWWeb.Data.Service.ProjectCharges");

    SOAPElement soapBodyEmployee = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Employee").addTextNode("26270");
    SOAPElement soapBodyFiscalYear = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("FiscalYear").addTextNode("2015");
    SOAPElement soapBodyAPIKey = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("ApiKey").addTextNode("APIKEY");
    SOAPElement soapBodyAppName = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("AppName").addTextNode("APPNAME");


    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "GetMyProjectCharges");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    /* Print the request message */
    System.out.print("Request SOAP Message:");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println();

    return soapMessage;
}
```

However I'm ending up with the following soap request code:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <GetMyProjectCharges xmlns="http://company.IWWeb.Data.Service.ProjectCharges">
            <Employee>26270</Employee>
            <FiscalYear>2015</FiscalYear>
            <ApiKey>APIKEY</ApiKey>
            <AppName>APPNAME</AppName>
        </GetMyProjectCharges>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Which the server doesn't seem to happy about.  Is there an easy way to modify what i'm doing to get a query string closer to what i want?