# Calling Ab-initio web service from java

Tags: java, ab-initio

I have created a web service in Ab-initio, **I want to call that web service from java**, I have read a lot information from help file. It gives me some information about plugin, but they have not mentioned it specifically that how to call service mentioned in plugin from java. Will anyone please guide me through it. 
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SOAP as your transport mechanism in RPC Subscribe -> Read XML Transform, the following link gives you a working example of a SOAP client: 
[Working Soap client example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948927/working-soap-client-example)

if you can test your web service using the component Call Ab-Initio RPC, and a record format of:

```
include "~$AB_HOME/connectors/RPC/rpcheader.dml";
include "~$AB_HOME/connectors/SOAP/SOAPRequest.dml";

metadata type = record
  rpcheader hdrs;
  SOAPRequest soaphdrs;
  utf8 string(big endian integer(4)) body;
 end;
```

then modifying the java code in the link to assign appropriate field name values should work.