# Jax-ws with https url ends up as http

Tags: java, https, jax-ws

I am attempting to call a webservice (developed in C#) using JAX-WS, over https. I have tried setting up an invocation through SoapUI, and this works.

But, when trying to do the same through a generated jax-ws client, all I get is a 301 response back. This is similar to what I get using SoapUI with a http url to the same service, and also wireshark tells me that I do a HTTP (HTTP/XML) POST operation. This leads me to belive that for some reason, my generated JAX-WS client attempts to invoke over http, instead of https.

Examplified code:

```
 new MyServiceInterface(new URL("https://acme.com/services/MyService.svc?wsdl"))
                       .getMyPort().test();
```

As you can see, I supply a `https` url when creating my client. Is there anything else needed in order to make sure that JAX-WS uses https? The namespace URIs are all http, could this cause problems?

Update:

I have implemented a SOAP-request for the service in quesiton using the guide from the accepted answer here: [Working Soap client example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948927/working-soap-client-example)
Pretty much repeated the information from SoapUI, and now it gives me the a proper 200 response.

Update 2:

When debugging my JAX-WS-client, I find this property:

```
"javax.xml.ws.service.endpoint.address" -> "http://acme.com/services/MyService.svc"
```

This has http, not https. Relevant?

Update 3:

When using the debugger to change "javax.xml.ws.service.endpoint.address" to the https url, rather than http, my client works. But why is it http to begin with?

Comment: Looks like an issue on server side. Try if you can access the server at port 443.

Comment: Since SoaPUI works, I would think the server works as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One cause could be if the WSDL referenced an `http` URL.

> new MyServiceInterface(new
>   URL("https://acme.com/services/MyService.svc?wsdl"))
>                          .getMyPort().test();

I'd suggest downloading `https://acme.com/services/MyService.svc?wsdl` and looking at the `<address>` or endpoint within the `<service>`. If it looks like this:

```
<soap:address location="http://acme.com/services/MyService.svc"/>
```

That could account for what you are seeing in the `javax.xml.ws.service.endpoint.address`.

If that's the case and you cannot control/fix the remote WSDL, you may need to programmatically override the endpoint:

```
MyServicePort myPort = new MyServiceInterface(new URL("https://acme.com/services/MyService.svc?wsdl")).getMyPort();
// set endpoint to use https
String endpointURL = "https://acme.com/services/MyService.svc";
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) myPort;
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointURL);
myPort.test();
```

Comment: I'll check it out, and as a side-note I got it working by setting the property manually. Just to get to the next problem (of course), with jax-b generating xml with the wrong name. Meh, life as a developer :p

Comment: Checked the WSDL, and you are correct, the address-element inside the service-element has a http URL. Could this be called a bug? Or is it just how things are done in .NET-created wsdls?

Comment: you avoid me a lot of headhakes! I was trying to fix the issue with system administrators without success. I notice the http reference in the wsdl but I was not sure it had an impact on the client call (having set a different endpoint). I tried your solution that works perfectly ;)

Comment: That solved my issue, thanks! It's weird that a SOAP request in java can't handle redirects tough, it seems like a big limitation, and the workaround seems hackish, having to dynamically cast to `BindingProvider` (and if in a newer version it stops implementing that interface, I would receive no errors at compile time, only at runtime) without a method to handle that (in `MyServicePort`, a method like `setEndpoint` or anything like that).