# Calling HTTPS URL in BindingProvider

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

One of the projects which I am now working on has this very old piece of code, which uses *BindingProvider* to call a WSDL client. But this BindingProvider sends in a HTTP URL as the endpoint. I have a requirement to change the endpoint to HTTPS and call the WSDL client. For the code which I tried, it is throwing PKIX certificate error. I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160902/jax-ws-with-https-url-ends-up-as-http) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001102/how-to-programmatically-set-the-sslcontext-of-a-jax-ws-client) SO questions, but not finding the answer which suits my code. Should I add .jks file anywhere in this code?

**Code**:

```
((BindingProvider) portType).getRequestContext().put(
                BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endPointURL);
portType.myMethod(myRequest(businessObj));
```

Where, endPointURL is the https URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you calling an endpoint with a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes. You're right.

Comment: So you have to import that certificate in the keystore