# Consuming SOAP requests in JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, jax-rs

I'm trying to extract a SOAP message from HTTP request to a REST endpoint.I'm using JAX-RS and no other libraries. Following is a sample soap request I'm planning to use

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns="http://example.com/ns">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <ns:request>
      <ns:customer>
       <ns:id>123</ns:id>
       <ns:name type="NCHZ">John Brown</ns:name>
      </ns:customer>
     </ns:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can you suggest me a method to do that.(I'm not allowed to use any SOAP engine)

Answer (score 0):

try to see this link, but i'm not sure about your restriction not to use SOAP engines
[Working Soap client example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948927/working-soap-client-example)