# client for webservicex.net from WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsimport

How do I actually [get the weather](https://askubuntu.com/q/1006601/45156) from `webservicex.net`?

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/javaClientGlobalWeather$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/javaClientGlobalWeather$ gradle clean shadowJar;java -jar build/libs/weather.jar 

> Task :shadowJar 
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shadowJar'. Registering invalid inputs and outputs via TaskInputs and TaskOutputs methods has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0.
 - No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.
The SimpleWorkResult type has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use WorkResults.didWork() instead.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
Feb 16, 2018 2:42:10 AM net.bounceme.dur.java.soap.weather.App run
INFO: begin
Feb 16, 2018 2:42:11 AM net.bounceme.dur.java.soap.weather.Weather getWeather
INFO: Data Not Found
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/javaClientGlobalWeather$
```

java [code](https://github.com/THUFIR/javaClientGlobalWeather):

```
package net.bounceme.dur.java.soap.weather;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.webservicex.GetCitiesByCountry;
import net.webservicex.GetWeather;
import net.webservicex.GetWeatherResponse;
import net.webservicex.GlobalWeather;
import net.webservicex.GlobalWeatherSoap;
import net.webservicex.ObjectFactory;

public class Weather {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    public void getWeather(String country, String city) {
        GlobalWeather gw = new GlobalWeather();

        GlobalWeatherSoap gws = gw.getGlobalWeatherSoap();
        String w = gws.getWeather(city, country);

        log.info(w);
    }

    public void getWeather3(String country, String city) {
        ObjectFactory o = new ObjectFactory();

        GetWeather gw = o.createGetWeather();

        gw.setCountryName(country);
        gw.setCityName(city);

        GetWeatherResponse gwr = o.createGetWeatherResponse();

        gwr.setGetWeatherResult(city);

        String r = gwr.getGetWeatherResult();

        log.info(r);

    }

    public void getWeather2(String country, String city) {
        log.info("getting weather");

        GetCitiesByCountry g = new GetCitiesByCountry();

        g.setCountryName(country);

        log.fine(g.getCountryName());

        GetWeather getWeather = new GetWeather();

        getWeather.setCountryName(country);
        getWeather.setCityName(city);

        log.fine(getWeather.getCountryName());
        log.fine(getWeather.getCityName());
        log.info(getWeather.toString());

        GetWeatherResponse weatherResponse = new GetWeatherResponse();

        log.info("weather response result:\t" + weatherResponse.getGetWeatherResult());

        log.info("end");
    }

}
```

the stubs were generated by `wsimport http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL -Xnocompile`.  Looking through the generated classes, not sure how to actually use [this service](https://askubuntu.com/q/1006601/45156) from Java.

Do Need to pass the WSDL to `GlobalWeather` or `GlobalWeatherSoap`?  That would be odd, since they were generated with `wsimport`.  Is this just a matter of knowing how to read the `WSDL`?

See also:

[Working Soap client example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15948927/262852)