# Sending SOAP message by Proxy in Java

Tags: java, soap, proxy

I need to know how to set a Proxy and confirm that it is working.

I have made a test program looking like this:

[image]

Where you can specify a proxy address and port number.

(I found the address and port on:
http://www.freeproxylists.net/)

The SOAP call is looking like this when "Use Proxy" is checked:

```
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_ADDRESS, PROXY_PORT);
        socket.connect(sockaddr, 10000);
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(socket.getInetAddress(), PROXY_PORT));
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
        return connection.call(message, uc);
```

Problem here is that the last row `SOAPConnection.call(..)` dose not allow `HttpURLConnection` as input and thereby gives:

> Bad endPoint type

Any idea how to add a proxy address to a SOAP call and verify that the proxy is in use?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

public class TestProxy implements ActionListener {

    public JTextField proxyField;
    public JTextField portField;
    public JCheckBox useProxy;

    // GUI
    public TestProxy() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Proxy tester");
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(f.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        proxyField = new JTextField("103.247.43.218");
        portField = new JTextField("8081");
        useProxy = new JCheckBox("Use Proxy");

        JButton b = new JButton("Connect!");
        b.addActionListener(this);

        f.getContentPane().add(proxyField);
        f.getContentPane().add(portField);
        f.getContentPane().add(useProxy);
        f.getContentPane().add(b);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    // ACTION
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        SOAPMessage response = null;
        try {
            SOAPMessage msg = createSOAPRequest();
            String urlStr = "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL";
            response = sendSOAPMessage(msg, urlStr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SOAPException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (response == null)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Null returned...");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Returned response!!!");
    }

    // SOAP CALL
    public SOAPMessage sendSOAPMessage(SOAPMessage message, String urlStr) throws SOAPException, MalformedURLException {

        String PROXY_ADDRESS = proxyField.getText();
        int PROXY_PORT = Integer.parseInt(portField.getText());
        try {
            SOAPConnectionFactory factory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection connection = factory.createConnection();
            if (useProxy.isSelected()) {
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_ADDRESS, PROXY_PORT);
                socket.connect(sockaddr, 10000);
                Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(socket.getInetAddress(), PROXY_PORT));
                URL url = new URL(urlStr);
                HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
                // This "call" is not allowed!!
                return connection.call(message, uc);
            } else {
                return connection.call(message, urlStr);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // SOAP MESSAGE
    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        return soapMessage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestProxy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working sendSOAPMessage method that use proxy:

```
public static SOAPMessage sendSOAPMessage(SOAPMessage message, String url, final Proxy p) throws SOAPException, MalformedURLException {
    SOAPConnectionFactory factory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection connection = factory.createConnection();

    URL endpoint = new URL(null, url, new URLStreamHandler() {
        protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
            // The url is the parent of this stream handler, so must
            // create clone
            URL clone = new URL(url.toString());

            URLConnection connection = null;
            if (p.address().toString().equals("0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:80")) {
                connection = clone.openConnection();
            } else
                connection = clone.openConnection(p);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000); // 5 sec
            connection.setReadTimeout(5 * 1000); // 5 sec
            // Custom header
            connection.addRequestProperty("Developer-Mood", "Happy");
            return connection;
        }
    });

    try {
        SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, endpoint);
        connection.close();
        return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Re-try if the connection failed
        SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, endpoint);
        connection.close();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would be an awful lot clearer if there weren't two different variables called `connection` used in there.

Comment: Oh, and two different variables called `url`.  This is making my head hurt.

Comment: Well @DawoodibnKareem, you could have edited the answer to make it clearer to everyone. That would be helpful to everyone here instead of your actual comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java `Proxy` class - more details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html). In essence, you can try whether your specified `Proxy` address is `reachable` or not. In case it is you can establish a `URL` connection (HTTP connection as shown below or your own protocol - like SOAP)
**EDIT:**

Using `SocketAddress` to try using the port value

```
   Socket socket = null;
        try {
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_ADDRESS,
                    PROXY_PORT);

            socket = new Socket();

            socket.connect(sockaddr, 10000);
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(
                    socket.getInetAddress(), PROXY_PORT));

            if (socket.getInetAddress().isReachable(10000)) {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.popofibo.com");
                HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection(proxy);
                System.out.println("Content: " + uc.getContentType());
                uc.connect();
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

In the above example, you establish a proxy connection and check if the `InetAddress` is reachable or not. If yes, you go forth and use your proxy to establish an http connection.

**EDIT:** Since `isReachable()`'s credibility is questionable, you can try catching the exceptions and buidling your own `boolean` flag, working example below.

Here you try the connection of the `proxy` using its address and port through `Socket` connection and catch the exceptions. I tested both the examples with my own proxy server and it works, it definitely fails for the `IP` mentioned by you in the example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        boolean proxyReachable = false;

        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_ADDRESS,
                PROXY_PORT);

        try {
            socket.connect(sockaddr, 10000);
            proxyReachable = true;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            proxyReachable = false;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            proxyReachable = false;
        }

        if (proxyReachable) {
            try {
                Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(
                        socket.getInetAddress(), PROXY_PORT));

                URL url = new URL("http://www.popofibo.com");

                HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection(proxy);
                System.out.println("Content: " + uc.getContentType());
                uc.connect();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Output (with a valid proxy address/port):**

```
Content: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks! The method isReachable() for "invalid-proxy.com" gives "UnknownHostException". But for my real proxy it return false. Any idea why it would return false?

Comment: @Grains yes it might be unreachable due to various reasons. You might want to try it with the increased timeout value - more details [here](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)). I tried to demo the proxy is reachable using this approach but you can work around it too, catching different exceptions.

Comment: Ok. My guess is that I need to specify the port also. But it seems like an "InetAddress" cant take any port numbers?

Comment: @Grains Look at the edit above, you can consume Port through `SocketAddress` class. I derive the `InetAddress` from it but in case you still get a false, get rid of the unreliable isRechable check and just catch a `SocketTimeoutException`

Comment: Ok. Still getting false which I do not know how to solve. Edited the question with an complete code example instead.

Comment: @Grains Refer to the edit above, you can build your own `boolean` to check for the proxy address validity. The ip in your example fails but my own corporate proxy works absolute fine with both the examples. The 2nd one would be more reliable since it consider your custom ports to connect to as well.

Comment: Your examples seems to work for me also on my local proxy(SquidMan). But I have no clue on how to use this with a SOAP connection.